# How to Upload To vsftpd default dir with scp

Tags: shell, scp, vsftpd

I have been working on uploading from shell and I need to upload from shell 
I found scp in openssh-client . and it work perfectly but in this command I have to set destination path in ftp server like this

```
sshpass -p'Password' scp file user@ftpserveradd:/destionationpath
```

is there any way I can use vsftpd default directory and not use destination path like the sample command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you issue the command

```
sshpass -p'password' scp file user@server:
```

it will copy *file* to the default home directory of *user* on server *server*.

Comment: Nope I try It too ...Several Time But Not Working :(

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There Is No Error Or Message .... If It was i may know what am i doing wrong but it work with out error and yet nothing Uploaded

Comment: I Found Problem ... Because I Changed default dir in vsftpd.conf it's don't upload .... Thanks For Your Help .,.. thanks Alot